# Правильная имитация долгой загрузки страницы

Tags: javascript, html

Сразу оговорюсь: я с JS не работаю, просто необходимо сделать тестовую веб-страницу. Логика у неё должна быть следующая:

1. При загрузке страницы изначально есть свой тайтл
2. Страница долго грузится (есть наработки, код будт ниже)

3а. Если страница загрузилась полностью, то тайтл меняется на другой

3б. Если загрузку страницы остановили (нажали в браузере "Стоп"), то тайтл остался прежним.

Мой код работает. Но временами, когда я начинаю грузить страницу, её head не прогружается. Страница грузится, блока head нет, тайтла нет, когда должен быть стандартный. Пытаясь вытянуть тайтл силами браузера, я получаю пустую строку вместо тайтла.
Как правильно заставить страницу ВСЕГДА показывать стандартный тайтл, потом долго грузиться (3-4 секунды. Это **принципиальный** момент), а потом при полной загрузке менять тайтл на какой-либо новый?

Моя наработка, которая работает с попеременным успехом:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>iPhone</title>
<script type="text/javascript">
    function myFunction() {
        var x = document.title;
        var i;
        for (i = 0; i < 15000; i++) {
            document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML += x;
        }
        document.title = "Android";
    }
</script>
</head>
<body onload="myFunction()">
    <p id="demo">loading</p>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Насколько я понимаю, проблема не в том, что head не грузится и title получается пустой строкой. Скорее всего так кажется, потому что вы не даёте браузеру времени отрисовать изменения на странице: браузер не может этого делать, пока исполняет непрерывный синхронный код. Как только вы добавите паузу даже в 1 миллисекунду, всё изменится. Правда, тогда стоит уменьшить число, потому что время «загрузки» существенно увеличится.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>iPhone</title>
<script type="text/javascript">
    async function myFunction() {
        var x = document.title;
        var i;

        for (i = 0; i < 1500; i++) {
            await new Promise(r => setTimeout(r, 1));
            document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML += x + ' ';
        }
        document.title = "Android";
    }
</script>
</head>
<body onload="myFunction()">
    <p id="demo">loading</p>
</body>
</html>
```

Но с этим подходом вы не получите возможность «остановить» загрузку, потому что ваша функция по условиям запускается уже после загрузки.

Comment: Дело в том, что как раз-таки и тестится опция остановки загрузки загрузки страницы. Логика в том, что смена тайтла и нужна для того, чтобы понять, что это именно Я остановил загрузку страницы и мне пришёл ивент COMPLETED после загрузки, а не я нажал на "стоп" и страница всё равно загрузилась. Смена тайтла мне нужна для того, чтобы видеть, что после остановки он не изменился, хотя должен был. Я просто не придумал, каким ещё образом можно понять, что именно Я прервал загрузку.

Comment: Я могу ошибаться, но это может быть невозможным средствами JS, пока вы по-настоящему что-то не загрузите. Я пытался, например, динамически создавать загружаемые элементы с большим генерируемым data-url, но нажатие на кнопку остановки всё равно не мешало им «догрузиться» и поменять title. Но, может, я неправильно это делал, и кто-то вам ещё подскажет)

Comment: Возможно вопрос прозвучит глупо, я далёк от веб-разработки. Но можно ли сделать тайтл пустым изначально, а потом асинхронно добавить в него  первый тайтл. После чего уже в онлоуде тайтл изменить на новый?

Comment: Я, к сожалению, очень смутно представляю, чего вы этим пытаетесь добиться. Надеюсь, кто-то сможет понять с полуслова. В своём ответе я просто пытался предложить версию, почему может казаться, что при «загрузке» тайтла нет или он вдруг становится пустой строкой. Но я не знаю, как эмулировать загрузку без загрузки)